# Nginx - How to let proxypass destination know the request is from Nginx?

Tags: nginx, proxypass

Below is my Nginx config -

```
location / {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_pass http://destination_server;
}
```

Is there any way for the `destination_server` know that the request is coming from the Nginx server?
A possible solution might `proxy_set_header Nginx-Name $custom_name`. And then on the `destination_server`, I can check the request header to see if the request is coming from a certain Nginx.
If there a better way for that? Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with adding the extra header? Other then that, your server could check the source IP, but that might not be a guarantee.

Comment: @MattClark Thank you for the answer. I was just not sure if there's a standard approach. Is there's common header var name? Thanks.

Comment: [Via](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Via) would probably be the most appropriate.

Comment: @MattClark That's what I'm looking for. Thank you!